# Shopware Docker on Mac OS ssh issue

Tags: docker, shopware

When I'm trying to run Shopware locally, I am able to start a Docker container. However, I am unable to ssh into it.

I'm following the readme exactly step by step.

First, I run:

```
./psh.phar docker:start
```

The container is running ok and has an id when I run docker ps.

Next, the readme says "ssh into the container with":

```
./psh.phar docker:ssh
```

Which gives me the following error:

> Error Output:
> ================
> No such service: app_server
> in /shopware-test/psh.phar/vendor/symfony/process/Process.php:232
> Stack trace:
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught
> Symfony\Component\Process\Exception\ProcessFailedException: The
> command "docker-compose ps -q app_server" failed.

I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong. I cloned the following repo:

https://github.com/shopwareLabs/shopware-docker

Here is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: "3"

services:

    shopware:
        # use either tag "latest" or any other version like "6.1.5", ...
        image: dockware/dev:latest
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "3306:3306"
            - "22:22"
            - "8888:8888"
            - "9999:9999"
        volumes:
            - "db_volume:/var/lib/mysql"
            - "shop_volume:/var/www/html"
        networks:
            - web
        environment:
            # default = 0, recommended to be OFF for frontend devs
            - XDEBUG_ENABLED=1
            # default = latest PHP, optional = specific version
            - PHP_VERSION=7.4

volumes:
    db_volume:
        driver: local
    shop_volume:
        driver: local

networks:
    web:
        external: false
```

Can someone point me in the right direction? Should I open an issue at the repo?

Comment: I just can recommend to use dockware https://dockware.io/ this works out of the box and is made by Christian Dangl, a docker guru Shopware also refers to. And it also works with Shopware 5

Answer (score 0):

I think you should name the container in your shopware service like:

```
    image: dockware/dev:latest
    container_name: examplename
    ports: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your docker-compose.yml file is already looking good.
the only thing you need to take care of is, not to mix up psh ssh stuff with regular ssh connections.

so your container uses dockware/dev and has port 22 exposed, which is great.
psh (did) just wrap some commands, but you already have it setup correctly.

just do a plain ssh (or in phpstorm) to localhost, port 22 and default credentials of dockware (dockware/dockware) in that case.

to get into the container, i would recommend the default docker way

```
docker exec -it (container_name) bash
```

then it should work

ps (saw the nice words from dnaumann, thx for that)